# Should I use a Timer, Handler or ASyncTask?

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, android-asynctask, handler

I have a thread which needs to be run in the background every 1000ms.
It can't be run in the UI as it freezes the app.
What method should I be using to do this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) seems to fit perfectly for me.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond. Timertask was the perfect solution. Thank you very much